# Data is not getting in Back End using ng-file-upload

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, ng-file-upload

I am using AngularJs for my front end.And i am using **ng-file-upload** for reading image and pass it to my back end, But it **sending REST** call to my back end but it doesn't send any data to my back end.
Code:

```
$scope.uploadData = function(){

    var tempData = {file: $scope.file, 'data': $scope.news};

    Upload.upload({
          url: '/createNEWS',
          data: tempData
    })

};
```

My Back End getting `{}` Means `null`

Comment: You need to post your backend code. The front end looks ok and you can verify it by looking at the content of the request in your browser's network tab.

Comment: Back End getting null Object

Comment: My Node server does not getting any data from angular....

Comment: Write your backend code in the question and a screen shot of the brwoser's network tab for the POST request being sent for upload.